# Is it OK to use Apple's sample code in my app?

Tags: iphone

I'm writing my first iPhone app. I want to use some methods from the sample code downloaded from Apple website, such as the PhotoScroller sample project.

Is it OK to do so? (Sorry I have no knowledge of copyright nor copyleft.)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely acceptable to include sample code provided by Apple in your own iPhone application.

Comment: Indeed, that is what they are hoping for.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: yes.

Apple's sample code usually comes with a copyright message, as long as you are not violating the terms of that message you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've actually seen *The Elements* app on the AppStore. It was free, however it made it up there without any problems whatsoever.

Not sure whether it's still on there though.